# jQuery mobile and double execution of the js

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I've attached files on bottom of the page (before body):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/mobile.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
```

in mobile.js is code like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('test')
});
```

and firebug returns me 'test' twice, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is recommended to use the `pageInit` event with jQuery mobile as opposed to `$(document).ready`.  See this page for more details: [jQuery Mobile Docs - Events](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html).

The code you could use:

```
$("#yourPage").live('pageinit', function() {
    console.log('test');
});
```

That may fix your problem.